# SCUBA upper or lower case?

Tags: capitalization, acronyms

In a university project which I am writing I have been reprimanded at least 10 times for using the word scuba in lower case. i.e. Scuba tank, Scuba diving etc. Is this permissible and can I tell my tutor that I will stick with my preference of lower case scuba.

Comment: If that's what your tutor wants, do what he tells you. No point in being reprimanded. Once he's no longer your tutor, do what you will.

Comment: However: [Oxford Dictionary Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/scuba). I really don't recommend using that in the circumstances.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6064/when-does-an-acronym-lose-its-capitalization-e-g-radar-radar

Comment: I disagree with @AndrewLeach in this case. Ask your tutor if _I used a laser welder to fix my SCUBA tank_ is OK. If he says 'yes', ask why _laser_ is acceptable but _scuba_ isn't. If you are feeling particularly belligerent you could suggest he was a member of 'The acronym Gestapo' (although he could correct you to GESTAPO). On another note - I don't think you should write _Scuba_ with a capital _S_ unless the sentence structure requires it.

Comment: "Scuba", with the first letter capitalized, is definitely wrong unless it's the first word of a sentence. "SCUBA" as the acronym, or "scuba" now that it has become an accepted and well-known word, are both more acceptable.

Comment: "Gestapo" is a poor choice of counterexample as it is always written in lowercase, even in German, as it's formed from just two words. (Only nouns and perhaps verbs tend to be capitalized in initialisms, leading to such expressions as GmbH for a limited liability corporation, where the "mb" are a preposition and adjective, respectively.)