# Is it appropriate to use "covid-19"/"covid" rather than "COVID-19"/"COVID"? Or should "Covid" be used? (Capitalization of COVID-19)

Tags: grammar, capitalization

The COVID-19 pandemic, as many have heard of, has been around for nearly 2 years. In such, there has been an increased usage of the word "COVID". My question here is should it be capitalized in any of the following ways?

- COVID/COVID-19
- Covid/Covid-19
- covid/covid-19

Alternatively, is there another capitalization that is more appropriate? It's become commonplace to hear people refer to "COVID" almost as if it has been adopted into the English language.

Comment: You could follow the advice in https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019/technical-guidance/naming-the-coronavirus-disease-(covid-2019)-and-the-virus-that-causes-it.  Or not, as you wish.

Comment: Here is a similar question (and answers): [Is it CoViD? Or COVID? Covid? How should the word be spelled?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/528487/is-it-covid-or-covid-covid-how-should-the-word-be-spelled) Does it answer your question?

Comment: Use whatever you want.  All sorts of manglings of the term have been used.  Mainly you should use the form that is common in the lingo you are using.

Comment: There are sadly many variants.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Unfortunately, very true.